# Show existing POST categories as items in the sidebar menu

Tags: plugins, admin-menu

For a cosmetics site, we have "Post" categories such as Deals, Skin Care, Body Care. All our content is saved as posts, in those categories. So all these posts show in the Posts menu in WP Admin, and once a user is inside this massive listing, he needs to filter every time by category and then wait.

Is it possible to show these categories as menu items in the left sidebar, WITHOUT creating "custom post type" which would require that we re-categorize all our 100s of posts. All we need is a mechanism to show categories in the left menu in a sensible way. Thank you for any pointers. (I've tried plugins like Adminize, but they do not do this.)